# Control Vaadin Heart beats

Tags: javascript, java, vaadin, vaadin7

Is there a way that we can control when to stop sending heart beats to server?.

My requirement is UI not to expire while user is typing into a text box or hovering mouse pointer over the UI.

Of course we can have some java script hack to send some server request when the user is doing some activity on the page which will eventually keep the UI from expiring.

But I would more like to control it through heart beats where if the user is really away from the UI then stop sending heart beats after a timeout but keep sending heart beats (at its defined rate) while the user is typing into a text box or hovering the mouse.

Whats the best way of handling this?

Comment: Should the UI expire at all? If not, then you can use the push mechanism for prevent expiring the UI

Comment: No, I want UI to be expired if the user is absolutely inactive

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want your UI being alive as long as there is user input. If the user idles the UI should be removed and not held up by heartbeats.

You do this by disabling the heartbeat mechanism. Setting the parameter `closeIdleSession` to `true` will do the trick.
In your web.xml write:

```
<servlet>
    ...
    <init-param>
        <param-name>closeIdleSessions</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

If the user triggers no request for the specified timeout time, the session is invalidated. This way your UI is destroyed after the session timeout is expired. The session timeout is set in the web.xml via

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout><!-- in minutes -->
</session-config>
```

By adding a `TextChangeListener` to your text field, typing will send requests and automatically will refresh the server timeout.

Comment: Your assertion in the first two lines is absolutely correct but the solution described is not what I expect. There are many text boxes in many views and adding a `TextChangeListener` for each is an overkill. I just need some hooks in to heart beat client APIs and If there isn't any user activity on top of the UI suppress the heart beats so the UI will get automatically expired. I believe this is possible as heart beats and detecting user activity on top of UI are both Java script things.

Comment: I admit the solution might not work for you, if the users are just typing and hovering over controls but don't actually submit any form input to the server. Say your session timeout is 60 minutes and the users are just hovering over the UI and typing but never press enter or any buttons for that duration, they finally are facing a session timeout. But is this really a scenario for your app?

Comment: This is an edge scenario. It seems currently the users are getting session time outs while keying in some hard to fill forms.

Comment: I see, what if you set your text field by default in immediate mode (setImmediate(true))? Your could do this easily with a factory method for the textfields. Then each time the user leaves the focus of the textfield a request is send to the server. If you have value change listeners attached to the textfield the field is implicitly in immediate mode and you don't have to set it.

Comment: Setting immediate true will serve it to some extent. But the demanding QAS will test it like nerds and for them the cases like users typing in a text box when the application is just about to time out or a user is thinking while hovering the mouse is not covered. So are you saying that we don't have any option to hook into heart beat Api and suppress or continue sending heart beats and control the time outs in that manner?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know a way that would allow you to change the heartbeat interval during run-time with Vaadin (E.g. switching it off with -1 and on with 300). I think you have to write your own solution with javaScript or GWT and integrate it into Vaadin as an add-on.

Comment: Exactly, so is there anyone who can lead me to some example showing me how to tap into Javascript or GWT internals?

Comment: Maybe this turn out to be useful for you: https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/timer